# Android WebView App Facebook share button

Tags: android, webview

I build an android app using Android Studio for my website. I build an Webview and i have 1 little problem. When i press share button from website like Facebook Share login work ok, i press share button but after share is complete i see just a white page.

Here is my main.java

```html
package totalonlinesrl.noiinbucatarie;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webView.loadUrl("http://noiinbucatarie.ro");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if( URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(url) ) {
                    return false;
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity( intent );
                return true;
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:open_menu()");
                    return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


}
```